# Why MutationObserver does not work for title change in FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers, fullcalendar-5

I need to know the current title of a FullCalendar. The title could be changed after clicking the navigation buttons.

[image]

I did not find any FullCalendar native way how to get the title so I was looking for other ways to find out. I thought that MutationObserver would work.. But it does not work when changing the text through the buttons. If the change is done via JavaScript

```
 var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
 var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
 
 calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
         
 })
   
 calendar.render()
   
 //More Details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver
 // select the target node
//var target = document.getElementsByClassName('ffc-toolbar-title')[0]
var target = document.getElementsByClassName('fc-toolbar-title')[0]
//var target = document.getElementById('1')
  console.log(target.innerText);  


// create an observer instance
//var observer = new WebKitMutationObserver(function(mutations) {
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  console.log(target.innerText);   
  console.log("comming from obeserver")
});
// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

setInterval(function(){
  //  target.innerText = ('hello world ' + Math.random() + '!!!');
},1000);
```

then the MutationObserver works.

Any idea how to fix that? Working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/radek/mdektyzu/20/)

Comment: Please show the code where you set up the MutationObserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to observe the changes resulting from clicks on the month increment/decrement buttons by adding `subtree: true` to the `config`.

From [MDN's page on "MutationObserver.characterData"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserverInit/characterData):

> Note that this doesn't monitor content of an HTMLElement, even if it only contains text inside, as it only monitors text nodes themselves. So either pass directly a text node to the observe() method or you need to also set subtree: true.

Comment: I could not find anywhere explanation on `config`. Thank you. It works now as intended.

Comment: Where did you find anything on what to use in config?

Comment: [MutationObserver.observe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe#parameters)